# Collapse all grouped sublists by default in Sharepoint using jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, document-library, jquery, script-webpart

I'm trying to edit script editor webpart in Sharepoint 2013 online (chrome removed) so that all grouped sublists would be collapsed by default. It's already set to collapsed by default in document library view options. But when i expand grouped list on the site it will be shown after page reload though.

Something like that was already discussed [there](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167037/how-can-i-collapse-all-groups-in-a-sharepoint-list-upon-page-load) but it still doesn't working to me.

Here is my last version.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".ms-commentcollapse-icon").click();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        $("span.ms-commentcollapse-iconouter").each(function(index, node) {
            node.click();
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Note**:

Make sure you have added this script editor after (below all list web-parts in page) all your list web-parts.

Comment: Does not work. ;(

Comment: Have you put inside document.ready()?

Comment: Yeap. $(document).ready(function () {
   document.querySelectorAll("span.ms-commentcollapse-iconouter").forEach(function(node) {
    node.click();
});
});

Comment: Try updated code from answer.

Comment: No changes. May be the problem is because it´s document library, not list?

Comment: Let me check for the document library and get back to you.

Comment: Or maybe it is because your code is executing first and the list/library content is loading after your code executes.

Comment: Try some options given in my answer [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251853/run-javascript-after-page-loads/251854#251854) to execute the code after page loaded completely.